# Multi level dropdown menu with padding around that doesn't disappear when going to submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Visuals speak for themselves:

```css
/* GENERAL STYLE */
#nav {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Category red */
.category{
  position: relative;  
  background: red;
}

/* highlight category items on hover */
.category:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* float and size li's */
#nav li {  
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top:-1px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

/* default off */
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/* a default off */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/* hover effect */
li:hover{
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE END */


/* hide dropdowns */
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;  
  padding: 10px;
}


.category:hover>.dropdown{
  display: block;
}

/* #nav ul li > ul > li */
 .dropdown li{
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.dropdown-subcategory{
  white-space:nowrap;
}

/* #nav ul li > ul > li > ul */
 .dropdown-subcategory .dropdown{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left:110%;
  background: red;    
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}


.dropdown li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}


#nav .subcategory-item {
  background: green;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="category">
      <a>Category</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-subcategory">
          <a>Category Item 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 3</a></li>
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to hover from **Category Item 1** to **Subcategory Item 1**, but submenu dropdown disappears when I try to move cursor to it. When you move mouse fast, submenu stays, but I think it is not wise to expect such level of dexterity from the user.

- How to make submenu dropdown stay with CSS without deleting *padding* on *.dropdown* class?

Comment: have a look at this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3 might help

Comment: @usrNotFound thanks already had before posting, the difference is that the dropdowns there have no padding around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my code snippet!

Changing `.dropdown-subcategory .dropdown` property `left` to `100%` does the job!

I delete the `padding` of `10px` on the `li` also for presentational purpose, you dont have to. Be sure that you use `margin` and `padding` on the `li` to get the best results.

```css
/* GENERAL STYLE */
#nav {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Category red */
.category{
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;  
  background: red;
}

/* highlight category items on hover */
.category:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* float and size li's */
#nav li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top:-1px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

/* default off */
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/* a default off */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/* hover effect */
li:hover{
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE END */


/* hide dropdowns */
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}


.category:hover>.dropdown{
  display: block;
}

/* #nav ul li > ul > li */
.dropdown li{
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
.dropdown li a {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}
.dropdown li.subcategory-item a {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.dropdown-subcategory{
  white-space:nowrap;
}

/* #nav ul li > ul > li > ul */
 .dropdown-subcategory .dropdown{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  top: 0%;
  background: red;    
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-subcategory .subcategory-item a{
  background: green;    
}

.dropdown li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}


#nav .subcategory-item {
  background: green;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="category">
      <a>Category</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-subcategory">
          <a>Category Item 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 3</a></li>
            <li class="subcategory-item"><a>Subcategory Item 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Category Item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry if it was impolite, seems to work. It would be great if you could comment your changes. Thank you.

Comment: I think you basically have to get a better structure in your code. Setting the navigation classes with a mix of `ul` `li` stuff and on the other hand with helper classes like `.subcategory-item` confused me. Set up a clear structure like `first-level`,`first-level-item`,`first-level-anchor` etc. would be the best approach. I removed padding everywhere I could find it and set in in the new two definitions I added `.dropdown li.subcategory-item a` and `.dropdown li a` (not so good because of mixed structure)